# How to replace text between double quote in string using JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS string which contain text between double quotes (`"`). I want to replace that text by another user-entered text by using RegEx but I do not know how to do that. For example:

Given string:

```
The book "A Farewell to Arms" will be published again.
```

New text: Gone with the Wind --> the above sentence will be

```
The book "Gone with the Wind" will be published again.
```

Could you please help me to solve this case? Sorry for this dummy question because I am new to JS RegEx.

Comment: Do you have problems with creating the expression or applying it in JavaScript? The expression is not different that what you us in other languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it..Spare me for my typo mistakes.I am not a javascript dev

```
str.replace(/".*?"/,"\"Gone with the Wind\"");
```

Comment: You could also use `"[^"]*"`.

Comment: @FelixKling I was fishing around for my own problem today, saw this comment, tried it and it worked. Another Felix Kling win, thanks :)

Comment: Just a note that this will not work if your string contains escaped quotes.

Comment: it only finding one match?